# Check if function will call another function or not

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am willing to write unit test for my Go application.

There is a function which will call another function, how should I confirm this call?

```
// the function which I wanna test
func big(t int) {

    bang(t * 6) // how to confirm this? 
}
```

---

I can't mock the `bang()` because it not belongs to any struct.

Answer (score 4):

In short, you do not. You'd test `bang` in it's own unit test if it needs to be verified. However, having functions which do not have a return value is tricky -- you can only test their behavior if they interact with something.

TL;DR: If you need to test behavior, make it as simple as possible to actually test the behavior. Especially when you test for behavior, test thoroughly: it makes your code more robust.

### Example

> Note: There are various ways to test behavior. I am showing a simple example.

A "better" (read: more concrete and transparent) example would look like this:

```
func hello(lang string) string {
    switch lang {
    case "de":
        return "Hallo"
    case "es":
        return "Hola"
    default:
        return "Hello"
    }
}

func world(lang string) string {
    switch lang {
    case "de":
        return "Welt"
    case "es":
        return "mundo"
    default:
        return "world"
    }
}

func greet(lang string) {
    var g string
    switch lang {
    case "de":
        g = fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s!", hello("de"), world("de"))
    case "es":
        g = fmt.Sprintf("¡%s, %s!", hello("es"), world("es"))
    default:
        g = fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s!", hello(lang), world(lang))
    }

    fmt.Println(g)
}
```

Now, the functions `hello` and `world` are easy enough to test. With the example of hello:

```
// TestHello is heavily simplified for brevity.
func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        desc     string
        lang     string
        expected string
    }{
        {
            desc:     "German",
            lang:     "de",
            expected: "Hallo",
        },
        {
            desc:     "Spanish",
            lang:     "es",
            expected: "Hola",
        },
        {
            desc:     "Default",
            lang:     "en",
            expected: "Hello",
        },
    }
    for _, tC := range testCases {
        t.Run(tC.desc, func(t *testing.T) {
            if hello(tC.lang) != tC.expected {
                t.Fail()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Repeat this for `world`, and you know that both function behave exactly as you expect them to behave.

But how would you test `greet`? It does not have a return value, and in its current form the only way to ensure something was written is to actually redirect the ouput of `os.Stdout`. That could well be enough, depending on your use case, but it is cumbersome and verbose.

So, it makes more sense to enhance your code to be testable:

```
// dsts is variadic to make it optional.
// So you can either call it as greet("en")
// or greet("en",whatever), with the added bonus
// that you can write to multiple destinations.
func greet(lang string, dsts ...io.Writer) {

    var g string
    var out io.Writer

    if dsts == nil {
        // If nothing is set, we want the default behavior.
        out = os.Stdout
    } else if len(dsts) == 1 {
        // If only one dst is set for example for unit tests *wink* *wink*
        // we can write to it directly.
        out = dsts[0]
    } else {
        // In case multiple dsts are set, we utilize multiwriter
        out = io.MultiWriter(dsts...)
    }

    switch lang {
    case "de":
        g = fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s!", hello("de"), world("de"))
    case "es":
        g = fmt.Sprintf("¡%s, %s!", hello("es"), world("es"))
    default:
        g = fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s!", hello(lang), world(lang))
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(out, g)
}
```

Testing this becomes stupidly simple:

```
func TestGreet(t *testing.T) {

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

    for _, lang := range []string{"de", "es", "unknown"} {
        greet(lang, buf)
        greeting := buf.String()

        // Of course, testing should be a bit more thorough
        if greeting == "" {
            t.Errorf("greeting for %s is empty!", lang)
        }

        if !strings.HasSuffix(greeting, "!\n") {
            t.Errorf("greeting '%s' for language '%s' has no exclamation mark or newline", greeting, lang)
        }
    }

}
```

More advanced techniques (for example for database connections) would be to [use mocks](https://blog.codecentric.de/2019/07/gomock-vs-testify/).

Comment: Thank you. I read the second part, two time. but still can't understand.

Comment: I there any full unit-tested  project in the earth?

Comment: @AminShojaei Some surely are. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: The `TestGreet()`  is confusing. What is the idea behind that?

Comment: @AminShojaei It is for testing the behavior of that function -- since it does not have a return value. So you add a buffer, which you can read, and then you can do all the testing in the world on the results that were written to said buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "test hook".

```
var testHookBang func(int)

func big(t int) {
    bang(t * 6) // how to confirm this?
}

func bang(i int) {
    if testHookBang != nil {
        testHookBang(i)
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

and then in your tests you can do something like this:

```
func TestBig(t *testing.T) {
    defer func() { testHookBang = nil }()

    var bangFunc struct {
        invoked  bool
        argument int
    }
    testHookBang = func(i int) {
        bangFunc.invoked = true
        bangFunc.argument = i
    }

    tests := []struct {
        bigArg      int
        wantBangArg int
    }{
        {10, 60},
        {5, 30},
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        bangFunc.invoked = false
        bangFunc.argument = 0

        big(tt.bigArg)

        if !bangFunc.invoked {
            t.Error("big did not invoke bang")
        }
        if bangFunc.argument != tt.wantBangArg {
            t.Errorf("unexpected bang argument: got %d want %d", bangFunc.argument, tt.wantBangArg)
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zd3BpliFgnu

Answer (score 0):

You could do either of these, but in general the second one (interface abstraction) is the way to go:

1. Assign your function to a package private variable, and then in the test create a simple wrapper like so (we have to reassign the function to `originalBang` as to avoid an infinite callback loop):

```golang
var bang = func(t int) {
    // your actual implementation
}

func big(t int) {
    bang(t * 6)
}

func TestBig(t *testing.T) {
    called := 0

    originalBang := bang
    testBang := func(t int) {
        called += 1
        originalBang(t)
    }
    bang = testBang

    big(5)

    if called != 1 {
        t.Error("bang was not called")
    }
}
```

2. If your function is a method (belongs to a struct), or contains methods you should create an interface that will allow you to create a simple mock, which in turn allows us to record called counter.

```golang
type Bang struct {
    // your actual implementation
}

func (b Bang) bang(t int) {
    // your actual implementation
}

type Banger interface {
    bang(int)
}

type mockBanger struct {
    called int
}

func (m *mockBanger) bang(t int) {
    m.called++
}

func big(t int, banger Banger) {
    banger.bang(t)
}

func TestBig(t *testing.T) {
    mock := &mockBanger{}

    big(5, mock)

    if mock.called != 1 {
        t.Error("bang was not called")
    }
}
```

Note that our mocked method has to have pointer reference to the struct, otherwise we'll pass a copy of the struct and won't be able to increment the counter.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't the first approach some kind of messy? Is it ok to put all functions into variables?

Comment: It is messy because the test case is kinda messy :) you don't test private contracts most of the time, if the bang function does something externally (like a db call), you should try to accept it as a parameter to your `big` function. To make it a bit cleaner you could also define a function type, like `type banger func(t int)` and change `big` signature to `big(t int, bang banger)`.